# Laravel - How to access a static variable with eloquent sub-function

Tags: php, laravel, function, static, eloquent

i'm very new to laravel and need help with a static function problem.

I want to access models within a sub-function created with the eloquent chunk functionality:

```
class test
{

public static function test_run ()
   {
   static $GlobalValues = GlobalValues::where("key", "test")->first();
   static $Stats = Stats::where("stat", "test")->first();

   User::chunk(1000, function ($users) {
                  ... some code ...
              %GlobalValues->test = "test";
              %GlobalValues->save();

              %Stats->statistic1 = 12345;
              %Stats->save();
              });


   }
}
```

Maybe, if this is possible, i would prefer if i could access to the $GlobalValues all over the application without to query it every time?

Comment: you can access it usin the `use` keyword like this `User::chunk(1000, function ($users) use($GlobalValues, $Stats ){....` !

Comment: it works, thanks a lot, i found nothing about "use" in the laravel documentation!

Comment: it's a php keyword not a laravel one ;)

Comment: oh, i forgot to say i'm in php new too, my failure then. But back to my second question, is it possible to make the GlobalValue model available all over the application?

Comment: You will be a web master i am sure of it ;)

Comment: How are you using this variable?  Are you attempting to make it available across all your views?  Or are you only needing this to be available in your controllers for example?

Comment: @Regnalf what you're asking about is globals.  Read the PHP manual on variable scope and globals.  Laravel also provides a way to store data in the app container so you can re-use it anywhere in your application.